# How can I integrate Gutenberg Block Editor with my ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.8, gutenberg-blocks, acf-gutenberg

I want to integrate Gutenberg Block Editor with my ASP.NET MVC (.NET Framework - not .NET Core) application.

I am trying to integrate block editor by using Standalone Gutenberg Block Editor with JavaScript (isolated-block-editor.js) but image block is not having upload image option. I think we cannot override or add custom block with isolated-block-editor.js.

Image Block (https://i.stack.imgur.com/qI1HH.png)

Can we customize Image Block with isolated-block-editor.js if not then can anybody guide me how to integrate this standalone Gutenberg Block Editor with ASP.NET MVC through React?